# How do I tell if an object is part of an Entity model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Essentially I'm trying to find a less awful way to do this:

```
foreach (var k in someList)
{
    try
    {
        var temp = Database.Set(k.GetType()).Local;
        newList.Add(k);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {

    }
}
```

`Database` is my `DbContext` instance for my model.

`someList` is a collection of objects, some are part of an Entity model, others are not. I want to create a new list (`newList`) that contains only the objects that are a part of the model. The objects in `someList` can be of any type (in my case one of these is `List<string>` which obviously has nothing to do with my underlying database).

The `InvalidOperationException` is raised when an object from `someList` is not a part of the Entity model. By doing this I get what I want, however it seems like a hack. I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: What are the types of `someList` and `k`? Can `someList` contain any type? And the method `Database.Set(k)` does not exist. Do you mean `Database.Set(k.GetType())`? Maybe give an example with concrete types.

Comment: someList can contain any type. And sorry, yes, that's a typo. I'll edit the question slightly.

Comment: The real problem is that you have a `someList` containing entities and non-entities. A good solution would avoid that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I can appreciate that, and in the greater scheme of things I think you are correct. However, that does not really help me right now.

Comment: I go with Henk. I think you should make the distinction where (and before) the list is created. There must be a place in your code where you can tell the origin of your objects. That's the place where you should initiate anything you want to do with entity objects.

Comment: Yeah, I think you guys are right and I'm going to look into that. I'll admit that I'll be just a little sad if there's no easy solution to my question. Would still be nice if one could nicely filter objects by type in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this answer so that anyone who finds this question can see how I resolved it. That being said, the real solution is to avoid having entities and non-entities in the same collection (as said in the comments to the original question).

To filter the collection `someList` you need to know which types are entities, and which are not. To do that I constructed a list of types from the properties of my `DbContext`.

```
types = (from t in typeof (Entities).GetProperties()
         where t.PropertyType.IsGenericType
         where
             t.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
             typeof (DbSet<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()
         select t.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]).Distinct();
```

`Entities` is the class which represents my database model (it inherits from `DbContext`).

This works by locating all the `DbSet<T>` properties in `Entities`, and then constructing a collection of all the `T` types. Each of these types represents an entity type.

To filter `someList` I simply check if the type of each member is contained in the collection `types`.

Answer (score 1):

This may not seem as a direct answer, but instead of trying to check using `DBContext` instance, you may just use a Marker interface. Then you may check directly, without using `DBContext`. For instance,

```
public interface IEntity
{
}

public clas SomeEntity : IEntity
{
    ... some properties
}
```

Also, as a side note, I wonder how you are able to store different types of instances in the same List.

Comment: I've considered something like this already, as I just happen to have an interface on most my entity classes. The obvious issue is the maintenance required. One would have to ensure that all relevant objects have this interface. Not ideal, but it's in the right direction.